# How can we do caching of WPF controls?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, caching

I am working on WPF application with lots of usercontrols and page takes 4 seconds to just show the UI.

`InitializeComponent()` method takes 3 seconds to process

How to cache the `UI controls` so at least next time user comes to same page. it loads instantaneously?

Answer (score 1):

The first way: after displaying the view for the first time, never collapse it again. Hide it instead (set Visibility to Visibility.Hidden). Thit works well, also for whole collections of views. You'll need your custom manager, which tracks what should be visible.

The second way: use Prism, and it's Region Manager.See https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/prism-showing-multiple-shells/table-of-contents - 'Controlling View Composition' module which talks about view caching.

The third way: recompose your view, to smaller pieces, use ContentPresenter to display them. Lazy load your data, initialize it from a different thread etc. You may have a strange corner case, like a 3rd party control that you MUST use, and which initialization takes ages, but more probably you have a design issue.